# Replacing scoped identifier with preprocessor #define

Tags: c++, namespaces, c-preprocessor, identifier

I want to declare the type of an object based on a preprocessor define. The problem is that the object type is qualified with namespaces:

`OldNamespace1::OldNamespace2::OldClass MyObject;`

Now when `__unit_test` is defined I want the compiler to see instead:

`NewNamespace1::NewNamespace2::NewClass MyObject;`

I have the source for OldClass but I don't own anything in `OldNamespace1`. I know I can do this obviously with `#ifdef` conditional includes, but this will require many `#ifdef` throughout the code. Is there a way to do it with just one (possibly compound) `#define`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to define a namespace like this:

```
#ifdef __unit_test
namespace myns = NewNamespace1::NewNamespace2;
class myclass : public NewClass {};
#else
namespace myns = OldNamespace1::OldNamespace2;
class myclass : public OldClass {};
#endif
```

Now you can simply define your objects via:

```
myns::myclass MyObject;
```